# How to set position on a list of undefined number of elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to do this:

I have a list of div like this, but I don't know how many items I could have

```
<div class="myClass" id="one"></div>
<div class="myClass" id="two"></div>
...
<div class="myClass" id="last"></div>
```

I want to set the absolute position of those, each depends from the precedent (you can image them as a line). For instance:

```
$('#one').offset({ top: 0, left: 0 });
$('#two').offset({ top: 0, left: ($('#one').width())+50 });
```

...

I have imagined that I could know their number by doing:

```
var itemNumber = $('#container').find('.item').size();
```

And then do a 'for' cycle like:

```
    for (var a = 0; a < itemNumber; a++) {
    $('.myClass').offset({ ... });
}
```

As you can see I'm stuck because my cycle must consider the position of the precedent element. And well, all divs have the same size.

ideas?

Comment: You should absolutely be able to accomplish this without absolute positioning. (haha, get it?) What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you wouldn't do this with CSS, but with jQuery, you could...

- use `.each()`
- starting with the second element, look back to the previous one,
- calculate the `left` of the current by adding the previous `left` to the previous `width`

---

```
var elems = $('.myClass');

elems.each(function( i ) {
    var prev = elems.eq( i-1 );
    $(this).offset({
        top: 0,
        left: i ? prev.width() + prev.offset().left : 0;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`$.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is very handy here:

```
var itemNumber = $('#container').find('#two').index();
```

Do note that the above will return `1`, as JavaScript arrays start from 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each()` to loop though all the items which match the slector:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(i) { });
```

And you can calculate the next position using:

```
(width of the item + 50) * i
```

Or if the items aren't evenly large you can create a variable with the cumulative value. Each time adding the width.